# Capture substrings contained in a string with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Hope you are fine.

I am not able to resolve my issue alone with a regex (in javascript).

I have the following strings :

ex 1:

```
error Lorem Ipsum warning dummy text info one more example for test error Another issue
```

ex 2:

```
error Lorem1 Ipsum1 error Lorem2 Ipsum2
```

For the two cases, I would like to split the text into 4 or 2 groups :

ex 1:

```
error Lorem Ipsum
warning dummy text
info one more example for test
error Another issue
```

ex 2:

```
error Lorem1 Ipsum1
error Lorem2 Ipsum2
```

I pretty sure that the solution is not really complicated.

Currently I am able to capture the keyword and the first characters but not all the characters (quantity of characters is not defined).

```
/((warning|error|info)(?:(^warning|error|info)*...))/gisu
```

And result is :

```
error Lo
warning th
info Lo
error An
```

Regex101 page : https://regex101.com/r/O9Jz5B/1

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you might be looking for `\b(?:warning|error|info)\b.*?(?=\s*(?:warning|error|info|$))`  https://regex101.com/r/WxCgZp/1

Answer (score 1):

In the pattern that you tried, this part `(?:(^warning|error|info)*...)` means matching optional repetitions of `warning` at the start of the string (which can not match, as you are not at the start of the string), or match `error` or match `info`.

Then match 3 times any char.

As the second 3 alternatives do not match after the first 3 alternatives, only the 3 characters `...` match and you get matches like

```
error Lo
     ^^^
```

---

You might use

```
\b(?:warning|error|info)\b.*?(?=\s*\b(?:warning|error|info|$)\b)
```

- `\b(?:warning|error|info)\b` Match 1 of the alternatives between word boundaries
- `.*?` Match as least as possible
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the rightis

  - `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
  - `\b(?:warning|error|info|$)\b` Match one of the alternatives or assert the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UR2bWz/1)

```js
const regex = new RegExp("\\b(?:warning|error|info)\\b.*?(?=\\s*\\b(?:warning|error|info|$)\\b)", 'gm')
const str = `error Lorem Ipsum warning dummy text info one more example for test error Another issue
error Lorem1 Ipsum1 error Lorem2 Ipsum2
`;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```